# Display relationship api data in html table - Angular

Tags: angular, angular-directive, angular11

Basically i have a relationship data in `educational_awards` and has a field `award`
[image]

Im trying to display that data to my html table but it wouldn't show.

```
<tr *ngFor="let item of data; let i = index">
  <td>
    {{ item.year }}
  </td>
  <td>
    {{ item.course }}
  </td>
  <td>
    {{ item.educational_awards.award }}
  </td>
</tr>
```

What i've tried is to add award type in my model but it shows ```undefined award``

```
export interface IUserEducationalBackground {
    id: number;
    user_id: number;
    studies_type: string;
    year: number;
    course: string;
    educational_awards?: EducationalAward ;
}

interface EducationalAward {
    id?: number;
    award?: string;
}
```

Am i doing this right or is this completely wrong. Fairly new to angular so im confused.

Comment: `item.educationalAward.award` do it need to be changed to `item.educational_award[0].award`?

Comment: Updated my code to item.educational_awards[0].award. Now its showing data thanks.

Comment: You can post it as answer bro

Comment: with my pleasure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`item.educationalAward.award` need to be changed to `item.educational_award[0].award`